# TextInput onChange - after setting state to '', onChange doesn't fire the first time, only second time and after

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput component like this:

```
<TextInput
    value={userMessage}
    onChange={textInputOnChange}
    ...
/>
```

Then this function to handle changes in the TextInput:

```
    const textInputOnChange = ({ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }) => {
        console.log("new text: " + JSON.stringify(text));
        setUserMessage(text);
    }
```

And from elsewhere, I'll call this function:

```
    const clearMainInput = async () => {
        console.log("Calling clearMainInput")
        setUserMessage('');
    }
```

Here's the buggy behavior that's happening:

1. I type 1 character into the text input - console log confirms that the onChange function fired
2. I type a 2nd character into the text input - same, all is fine
3. I call clearMainInput - the input does get cleared, suggesting that function runs fine, and moreover I get a console log from textInputOnChange: `new text: ""`
4. I type 1 character into the text input - *nothing happens* - this is the weird part. No console log, which suggests onChange doesn't fire
5. I type a 2nd character into the text input - textInputOnChange fires and I see the console log, with both characters

Why doesn't onChange fire for the first change after I set userMessage to ''?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code please? There's no issue in what you've shared, so it should be somewhere else. Also, instead of digging into the event with onChange, you can get  only the text from onChangeText.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your code and it run what I expected. When I type something, I see `"new text: value "` . I create a button and I give clearMainInput function to onPress event of the button. When I press the button, onPress event of button not triggered because I don't change TextInput with my hand.Then when I started to type, onPress event triggered. Here my App.js file. My react native version is 0.70.6

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';



const App = ()=> {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState("")
  const clearMainInput = async () => {
    console.log("Calling clearMainInput")
    setUserMessage('');
    }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView >
    <TextInput 
        value={userMessage}
        onChange={(e)=>{
          console.log("new text: " + JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.text));
          setUserMessage(e.nativeEvent.text);
        }}
    />
    <Button title='Clear' onPress={clearMainInput}  />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};



export default App;
```